# Replacing a key in a JSON file with python

Tags: python, json

I am doing a simple python script to replace a key in my JSON file, the following is my python script

```
import json
import os

json_dir="/opt/rdm/adggeth/ADGG-ETH-02/20181008/"
json_dir_processed="/opt/rdm/adggeth/ADGG-ETH-02/20181008updated/"
for json_file in os.listdir(json_dir):
    if json_file.endswith(".json"):
        processed_json = "%s%s" % (json_dir_processed, json_file)
        json_file = json_dir + json_file
        print "Processing %s -> %s" % (json_file, processed_json)
        with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
            json_data = json.load(f)
            if "grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile" not in json_data:
                json_data["grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile"] = json_data["grp_farmerdts/hh_id"]
        with open(processed_json, 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
    else:
        print "%s not a JSON file" % json_file
```

This scripts gives me the following error:

```
    File "/opt/rdm/adggeth/ADGG-ETH-02/addfidkey.sh", line 16, in <module>
    json_data["grp_farmerdts/hh_id"] = json_data["grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile"]
KeyError: 'grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile'
```

How can i successfully replace the key of my JSON file

My sample JSON file is as follows: I have deleted most of the details in my JSON file for easier understanding

```
  {

    "grp_farmerreg/members_no": "1", 
    "grp_farmerreg/hh_country": "1", 
    "_bamboo_dataset_id": "", 
    "_tags": [], 
    "grp_farmerreg/totanim": "6", 
    "gpsloc": "7.0854258 38.6111001 1674.300048828125 17.0", 
    "grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile": "0913886615", 
    "grp_farmerreg/grpdetails2/nmale6to14": "1", 
    "grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmerhhhead": "1", 
    "grp_farmerreg/grpdetails2/nfem15to64": "0", 
    "meta/instanceID": "uuid:008aea99-810e-4dbc-9235-4d02b8e8d36b", 
    "_duration": "",     
    "grp_farmerreg/grpdetails2/nfem6to14": "1", 
    "grp_farmerreg/grp_e1_ctlca/cattletotalowned": "6", 
    "start_time": "2018-12-24T11:24:53.034+03", 
    "_uuid": "008aea99-810e-4dbc-9235-4d02b8e8d36b", 

}
```

my expected output

```
{

    "grp_farmerreg/members_no": "1", 
    "grp_farmerreg/hh_country": "1", 
    "_bamboo_dataset_id": "", 
    "_tags": [], 
    "grp_farmerreg/totanim": "6", 
    "gpsloc": "7.0854258 38.6111001 1674.300048828125 17.0", 
    "grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile": "0913886615", 
    "grp_farmerdts/hh_id":"0913886615", 
    "grp_farmerreg/grpdetails2/nmale6to14": "1", 
    "grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmerhhhead": "1", 
    "grp_farmerreg/grpdetails2/nfem15to64": "0", 
    "meta/instanceID": "uuid:008aea99-810e-4dbc-9235-4d02b8e8d36b", 
    "_duration": "",     
    "grp_farmerreg/grpdetails2/nfem6to14": "1", 
    "grp_farmerreg/grp_e1_ctlca/cattletotalowned": "6", 
    "start_time": "2018-12-24T11:24:53.034+03", 
    "_uuid": "008aea99-810e-4dbc-9235-4d02b8e8d36b", 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the lines

```py
if "grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile" not in json_data:
    json_data["grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile"] = json_data["grp_farmerdts/hh_id"]
```

with

```py
if "grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile" in json_data:
    json_data["grp_farmerdts/hh_id"] = json_data["grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile"]
    del json_data["grp_farmerreg/farmerdetails/farmermobile"]
```

Comment: i have tried your solution but i get the same error @Julian Minde

Comment: Did you change the first line of my answer as well? The Key error says that the key "grp_farmerdts/hh_id" does not exist in your json_data, which seems correct. However, by assigning it you add it and that should be fine. If you tried this solution and got key error it should mention another key.